# Referencing a View from another View in InterfaceBuilder

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, ipad

Is it possible to position a view defined in a XIB as a subview in yet another view in that same XIB file?  Alternatively, is there a way the "subview" can be defined in another XIB file and positioned in the first view in a different XIB? I've figured out how to do this for UIViewControllers but not for UIViews.  Has anyone figured out how to do either of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view your nib file objects in a tree view and drag and drop one view to be a subview of another.